# Side book for Tao's Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I have started reading Tao's Analysis-1 and want recommendation for some other book to be used in combination with it as a source of Exercises. I have one analysis book written by Bartle, can it be used?(I am asking this because I have not yet read Bartle)

**Note:** I am not enrolled in any university programme and I will be doing it myself so please answer accordingly.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I too am making use of Tao's Analysis Volume One for learning Analysis. Based on what i have learned from looking around and from my own experience i can recommend the following texts.

- ***Numbers and Functions, Steps into Analysis by R.P. Burn***
- ***Elementary Analysis- The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth A. Ross***
- ***Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott***

  ---

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you give some review of exercises in Bartle's Text

Comment: @MrigankShekharPathak Sorry but i haven't used Bartle so i cant say.